# Python not recognizing input as correct when checked against another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, passwords

TL;DR - read the title, dammit

I'm fairly new to python - more specifically, file handling in python - and I'm working on something for school; I'm trying to make simple log in system (no security or anything, just the basic frame of one) in python alone. I was wondering about the best way to go about this. The method I've thought up is to have a set folder in a set directory, which contains files all named according to the username of the password they store (for example, "jacksonJ.txt" would hold that user's password). The user then inputs their username, python fetches that file, reads the password, then checks the user's inputted password against the actual one. MY PROBLEM IS; even when the correct password is inputted, python doesn't seem to recognize that.

```
from pathlib import Path
usr=input("Username: ")

#creating a filepath to that user's password document
filepath=("C:\\python_usr_database\\"+usr+".txt")

#make sure that file actually exists
check= Path(filepath)

#if it does, let them enter their password, etc
if check.is_file():

    #open their password file as a variable
    with open (filepath, "r") as password:
        pass_attempt=input("Password: ")

        #check the two match
        if pass_attempt==password:
            print("Welcome back, sir!")
        else:
            print("BACK OFF YOU HACKER")

#if it isn't an existing file, ask if they want to create that user
else:
    print("That user doesn't seem to exist yet.")
    decision=input("Would you like to create an account? y/n ").lower()
    # do some stuff here, this part isn't all too important yet
```

Comment: `password` is the file, not its contents. You need to `.read()` the file to get its contents

Comment: Thank you! Like I said, I'm fairly new to this...

Answer (score 1):

To get the content of the file you need to do file.read(). This returns a string of the content.
So:

```
with open(filepath, "r") as password_file:
    password = password_file.read()
password_attempt = input("password: ")
# Compare, then do stuff...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a file when you open it to get its contents - your issue was that you were comparing a string against a file. Try the following:

```
from pathlib import Path
usr=input("Username: ")

#creating a filepath to that user's password document
filepath=("C:\\python_usr_database\\"+usr+".txt")

#make sure that file actually exists
check= Path(filepath)

#if it does, let them enter their password, etc
if check.is_file():
    #open their password file as a variable
    with open (filepath, "r") as f:
        password = f.read()
    pass_attempt=raw_input("Password: ")

    #check the two match
    if pass_attempt==password:
        print("Welcome back, sir!")
    else:
        print("BACK OFF YOU HACKER")
#if it isn't an existing file, ask if they want to create that user
else:
    print("That user doesn't seem to exist yet.")
    decision=input("Would you like to create an account? y/n ").lower()
    # do some stuff here, this part isn't all too important yet
```